# Column Type "Number" in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Could any one please say the **maximum number of digits** that can be stored in a column of type **Number** in SharePoint?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Number field allows the user to store value upto 1E+308 .

Comment: Thank you. confirmed the same(1.79E + 308) in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd588079(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can find all Site column types and options on this web page:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Site-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7#__toc277149824

Comment: but here i find only this line which says about currency column type "Unlike a Number column, a Currency column is accurate 15 digits to the left of the decimal point and 4 digits to the right."

Answer (score 1):

I guess it will not take value bigger than **79228162514264300000000000000**.

Because `decimal.MaxValue` in C# we get this value.